# Kafka Consumer doesn't always receive messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, streaming

So I have this Kafka Consumer but it isn't always receiving messages from my producer and I'm not sure if it has to do with the Zookeeper/Kafka servers dying randomly or something to do with the code.

Was wondering if this is a common issue?

Producer:

```
    public SentenceProducer() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("client.id", SentenceProducer.class.getName());
        producer = new KafkaProducer(properties, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
    }
```

Consumer:

```
    public SentenceConsumer() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("client.id", SentenceConsumer.class.getName());
        properties.put("group.id", "test");
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer(properties, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("sentence"));
        detector = new LanguageDetector();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your polling code - and confirm that some messages are sent after you consumer starts polling - thx

Comment: Also a bit on your broker setup. You could lose messages if you have replicas that are falling behind, because the default acks in producer config is 1, and that does not guarantee delivery (see https://chrisg23.blogspot.com/2020/02/kafka-acks-configuration-apology.html?m=1)